# Set JS variable as text input value

Tags: javascript, textbox, getelementbyid

I have a java script, getting domain name of webpage like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function getDomain()
{
var x = location.hostname;
document.getElementById("domain").innerHTML=x;
document.getElementById("Field25").value=x;
}
</script>
```

and I have a text box, that I need the x to be its value, like this:

```
<input id="Field25" name="Field25" type="url" class="field text medium" maxlength="255" tabindex="4" required />
```

its not working
what should i do?

Comment: If you add console.log(x) to the code (at the end of the function) what does x equal?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? what is the output of typing `document.getElementById("domain")` in your browser console?

Answer (score 4):

You're telling it to make a string "x" the value of field25. Just use the variable x.

```
document.getElementById("Field25").value = x;
```

Get rid of the `window.onload`. You've got the syntax wrong anyway. You're trying to do

```
window.onload = function() {
// Some code here
}
```

You're currently redefining window.onload as the function getDomain(), then never calling getDomain().

If you get rid of the window.onload completely, the code will do what you want.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qLhn8/

*Aside: It's possible that window.onload isn't running under the context of jsfiddle, so you may need it after all.*

Comment: tried it before, didn't work either

Comment: @BacheRostam Could it be that the field is loaded after the page load, or getting rewritten by something else? for example loading the fields with AJAX, or using JSF (implying Java)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quiet understand, but if you mean that you want the `input#Field25` to have the value from the x variable, look closer because you are assigning the string `'x'`, not the value from the variable `x`

Update your code to this:

```
document.getElementById("Field25").value = x;
```

Comment: ur right, that was not what i meant, i changed it, but it didn't work too